# Upgrade Django from 1.6.2 to latest version (~1.8)

Tags: python, django, migration

So I've been tasked with upgrading a Django server from 1.6.2 to the latest (~1.8), along with upgrading Python from 2.7.3 to 3.3. I suspect this is going to break quite a bit of code. (I even need to upgrade the Ubuntu installation from 12.04 to 14.04)

I would like to migrate my Django app from the server it's currently running on (Ubuntu 12.04) to a virtual machine, and use that environment as a sandbox to make changes.

Would anyone be so kind to provide guidance on django app migration? Please let me know if you'd like me to provide any specific details.

Thank you.

Edit: If anyone would like to vote down this question because they believe I haven't done enough research, I'm very happy to add missing information, if I know what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you using Git to deploy the code? If yes, I would create a virtualenv, clone the repository, upgrade all of the packages, upgrade Ubuntu, and push the new deployment. Changing from Django 1.6 to 1.8 won't have much refactoring to do. There are minor instances, but most of the old code should still work. If you really want to dive in it, Django 1.8 will help you shorten a lot of code, but you shouldn't need to re-do much to get started.

Comment: I second @jape thoughts.  Use virtual environment and git.  upgrade django first.  Once that works, move on to upgrade of python code.

Comment: @joelgoldstick Great minds think alike (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django versions from 1.5 onwards has been designed so that the same code will work on both versions of Python as in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/) thanks to them following the [six compatibility layer](http://pythonhosted.org/six/).

You might face some issues with code that isn't strictly related to Django components like print statements and other such parts that might have been coded in. The official [Python Porting Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) should held you with that.


Django 1.8 is a LTS (Long Term Release) so it's a good idea to upgrade to it. Migrating the database might be a bit of an issue considering it's from 2.7 to 3.4 but that's in all likelihood the place you'll find most issue with. The [How to Migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/upgrade-version/) is a great resource.

If I recall correctly the directory structure is a bit different in 1.6 so you'll have to move some code and files manually. I suggest having the tutorial pages for both versions [1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) and [1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) open and comparing the directory structure. 

Going through the first 2 pages of the tutorial should give you enough of an overview to migrate the database and the `settings` file. This should also help with [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#supporting-python-2-and-3).

The 3rd and 4th pages should get you through migrating the `views` and `urls` files.

The only thing I'm not familiar with is the migration of the `wsgi` file which has configuration information, you should be able to find some basic information about that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/). 

Updating your Ubuntu however won't change or affect anything at all.

Also as has been said in the comments by jape and joel, it's a good idea to use `virtualenv` and git. 

I would like to add another suggestion based on my own experience with pushing code to a Django server : 

Download the code base to your local machine and work there and once you're done and the server is working well on your machine push it all to the server at once. That way you can isolate server machine specific issues from coding issues.